# Should a serialized/deserialized connection-string be case sensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, connection-string

How can I deserialize a string in case-sensitive way? It looks like serialization is case-sensitive, what's the point in deserialization being not case-sensitive??

[image]

**UPDATE**: trying to localize where and what is going on under the hood, I've set up DEBUGGER to download symbols and stepped into the FCL .NET code. I've stuck near these code (DbConnectionOptions.cs lines 873-921):

```
private static NameValuePair ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, bool firstKey) {
    Debug.Assert(null != connectionString, "null connectionstring"); 
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    NameValuePair localKeychain = null, keychain = null;

        int nextStartPosition = 0; 
        int endPosition = connectionString.Length; 
        while (nextStartPosition < endPosition) {
            int startPosition = nextStartPosition; 

            string keyname, keyvalue;
            nextStartPosition = GetKeyValuePair(connectionString, startPosition, buffer, firstKey, out keyname, out keyvalue);
            if (ADP.IsEmpty(keyname)) { 
                // if (nextStartPosition != endPosition) { throw; }
                break; 
            } 

            string realkeyname = ((null != synonyms) ? (string)synonyms[keyname] : keyname);
            if (!IsKeyNameValid(realkeyname)) { 
                throw ADP.KeywordNotSupported(keyname); 
            }
```

The modification occurs somewhere inside the while loop, which looks for another key/value pair in every iteration. Unfortunately I can't 'add watch' to keyname and realkeyname variables. I suppose synonyms Hashtable is also important here.

- how can I see these variable values?
- what should I do next to finally find the exact place of modification?

Comment: Confused , Now what is your question actually ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because ([as per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx)) for connection strings:

> Keywords are not case sensitive.

The values, however, *are* case-sensitive (obviously, for passwords etc)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. This indirectly solved my problem but I am more confused on deserialization case-insensitivity. I will check the why this happens as Kragen suggested. Just need to configure symbols downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Serialisation definitely is case sensitive, however your connection string doesn't need to be - are you sure that your ConnectionString property isn't doing something weird, for example:

```
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return this._ConnectionString;
    }
    set
    {
        this._ConnectionString = value != null ? value.ToLower() : null;
    }
}
```

Note that the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` appears to do some case "normalisation" of connection strings, i.e. the "weirdness" doesn't necessarily need to be in your code.

Try executing `info.GetValue("ConnectionString", typeof(string));` in a debugger and seeing what you get back.

Comment: Exactly, the normalisation is for sure not in my code. I've set up IDE for source debugging, but I've stuck somewhere close to the 'problem'. Can You advise me the next step which will help me to find the problem?

Comment: @dygi Find out if its the property thats normalising the string or not (by inspecting the value that the property is set to in the immediate / watch window), and if it is the property just debug and step through to narrow down when this happens.

Comment: Both watch and immediate cannot obtain value of local argument .. possibly it has been optimized away. I've checked all my projects properties and all 'Optimize code' checkboxes are unchecked. Is there any other place where can I turn optimizations on/off?

Comment: I've also tried to add '[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]' as an attribute to my constructor. Still can't obtain these variables values.